# Make Curve Have A Fill and Border

Tags: materials, bezier-curves, mirror, vector

[image: lips|690x388]

Setting a fill and border is pretty easy in apps like Illustrator and Gravit Designer but in Blender. I've found it to be more tedious as I can't find anything online to solve this problem.

The picture above is a simple 2d mouth with lips. I would like to be able to move the lips and still have a fill but in Blender I needed to add another path for the mouth. Is there anyway I can move my lips path while having it also take the exact same shape (but not material) as my mouth's path?

[image: lips|690x388]
[lips.blend|attachment](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/akN08tyKy6HANUBlfXvqVpryvq2.blend) (454.2 KB)

I work in Blender 2.79 cause 2.8 doesn’t run well on my laptop at all.

Comment: This is more characteristic of a Grease Pencil object .. is it possible that could fit, in your case? Maybe describe how you are using this mouth.. simple 2D.. attached to geometry.. etc..

Comment: Negative, I work in Blender 2.79 cause 2.8 doesn’t run well on my laptop at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since curves can't be rigged, the only way I see it is using Hooks.

Enter *Edit Mode* and hook each separate curve vertex you wish to move independently to a new object using the option *Hook to new Object*.

[image]

Then go into the second curve and repeat the process. For vertex you want to move together first select a existing empty you wish to hook it to, then enter *Edit Mode*, select said vertex and use the other option *Hook to selected object*.

[image]

If two vertex from different curves are hooked to the same empty they will move together. If you still want some independence occasionally you can always hook to separate empties, the parent two empties to a third "controller" empty that moves both simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way:

- create a **Circle** curve
- Create another circle and scale it down on one axis to get an oval
- use an oval as **Bevel Object** in the *Curve* properties
- move the circle to move the mouth (it's your path), and modify the oval to modify the thickness/shape

[image]

Comment: I already do that to set the lips. My question pertains to, how do I move my lips curve and my mouths curve simultaneously so I don't have to keep moving each one by one. Hence why I also included the small .blend project file.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question