# How to create those kind of lips?

Tags: modeling

I am a total beginner in modeling and trying my best to replicate some cartoon icon and I managed to make the body, nose and eyes but I don't know how to make the lips, I want to make the lips and shape key it into smiles, or sadness, etc..

I tried using cube with subsurfaces and extruding, tried curves but I feel like I am just lost.

These are the lips

[image]

And this is my work so far:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.blendernation.com/2021/02/04/how-to-work-with-bevel-bezier-curves-blender-2-9-update/

Comment: In your case, use a Bezier circle with the linked video above.

Comment: there are many ways, do you want the lips to be part of the head mesh? or can it be a curve? how do you plan to rig and animate the lips? etc

Comment: @moonboots I don't know what are the advantages and disadvantages of all of these, but I want lips to animate them into a smile or into a sad face

Comment: does the link given by Duarte answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154144/make-curve-have-a-fill-and-border